# Substring to hash key issue?

Tags: ruby, hash, substring

I have a log file and need to create a hash key for each URL in the record. Each line from the record has been placed into an array and I am looping through the array assigning hash keys.

I need to get from this:

```
"2010/08/23 15:25:35 [error]: (4: No such file or directory), clent: 80.154.42.54, server: localhost, request: "GET /logschecks/scripts/setup1.php HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
```

to this:

```
"/logschecks/scripts/setup1.php"
```

I have tried using `match`, `scan` and `split` but they have both failed to get me where I need to go.

My method currently looks like:

```
def pathHistogram (rowsInFile)
  i = 0
  urlHash = Hash.new

  while i <= rowsInFile.length - 1

    urlKey = rowsInFile[i].scan(/<"GET ">/).last.first

    if urlHash.has_key?(urlKey) == true
      #get the number of stars already in there and add one. 
      urlHash[urlKey] = urlHash[urlKey] + '*'
      i = i + 1

    else 

      urlHash[urlKey] = '*'

      i = i + 1

    end
  end
end
```

I know that just scanning the "GET " won't complete the job but I was trying to baby-step through it. The `match` and `split` versions that I tried were fairly epic-fails, but I was likely using them incorrectly and they are long gone.

Running this script gives me an undefined method error on "first", though I have gotten other errors when I vary the way this is handled.

I should also say I am not married to using `scan`. If another method would work better, I would be more than happy to switch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need to see what you've tried. As is, you've given us the error you receive, but no code to work with. *HOW* did you use `match`, `scan` and `split`? What is your hash supposed to look like?

Comment: Edited with more information. Thank you.

Comment: I think you need single quotes around the input line and no (unmatched) double quote at the beginning.

Comment: Cary, I am not sure I follow you. By input line, do you mean the GET?

Comment: Do you *only* need GET requests? Or, do you also need to capture HEAD, POST and other actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state in a comment to the other answer the pattern is basically `"GET ... HTTP`, where you are interested in the `...` part. That can be extracted very easily:

```
line = '2010/08/23 15:25:35 [error]: (4: No such file or directory), clent: 80.154.42.54, server: localhost, request: "GET /logschecks/scripts/setup1.php HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"'

line[/"GET (.*?) HTTP/, 1]
# => "/logschecks/scripts/setup1.php"
```

Comment: That was the solution thank you. One question, why the "?"? I understand that the .* means any amount of any character, but what does the ? do? Thank you again.

Comment: @joerdie It will make the matching non-greedy (or; lazy), i.e., it will stop as soon as it encounters HTTP, instead of trying to make HTTP part of the `.*`. For example, if the line would be `'"GET /some/path HTTP/1.1 other_log_stuff HTTP/X.Y'`, and we use `/"GET (.*) HTTP/` (without `?`), it would return `"/some/path HTTP/1.1 other_log_stuff"` (it matches the first HTTP as `.*` and stops only at the last HTTP). You can Google 'regex lazy quantifiers' for more info. With the lazy quantifier, the match on that String would be `"/some/path"`, like we want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each of your input lines contains `/logschecks/...`:

```
x = "2010/08/23 15:25:35 [error]: (4: No such file or directory), clent: 80.154.42.54, server: localhost, request: \"GET /logschecks/scripts/setup1.php HTTP/1.1\", host: \"www.example.com\""


x[%r(/logscheck[/\w\.]+)] # => "/logschecks/scripts/setup1.php"
```

Comment: Well. Not all will contain "/logschecks" but they do all contain ""GET " before the URL and " HHTP" after it. Changing you code to [%r(GET[/\w\.]+)] results in a bunch of blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

Scanning HTTP logs isn't hard, but how you go about it will vary depending on the format. In the sample you're giving it's easier than a standard log because you have some landmarks you can look for:

- [Search for `request: "`](http://rubular.com/r/CZSQMtPRCB) using something like:

  ```
  /request: "\S+ (\S+)/i
  ```

  That pattern will skip over `GET`, `POST`, `HEAD` or whatever method was used for the request.

  ```
  log_line[/request: "\S+ (\S+)/i, 1] # => "/logschecks/scripts/setup1.php"
  ```

  You might want to know that if you're mining your logs. In that case...
- [Search for `request: "[GET|POST|HEAD|...]`](http://rubular.com/r/8Lvw26n8XV) using something like:

  ```
  /request: "(\S+) (\S+)/i
  ```

  You'd use it like:

  ```
  method, url = log_line.match(/request: "(\S+) (\S+)/i).captures # => ["GET", "/logschecks/scripts/setup1.php"]
  method # => "GET"
  url # => "/logschecks/scripts/setup1.php"
  ```
- You can also [grab whatever is inside the double-quotes](http://rubular.com/r/25sFCO91zP), then split it to get at the parts:

  ```
  /request: "([^"]+)"/i
  ```

  For instance:

  ```
  log_line = %[2010/08/23 15:25:35 [error]: (4: No such file or directory), clent: 80.154.42.54, server: localhost, request: "GET /logschecks/scripts/setup1.php HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"]
  method, url, http_ver = log_line[/request: "([^"]+)"/i, 1].split # => ["GET", "/logschecks/scripts/setup1.php", "HTTP/1.1"]
  method # => "GET"
  url # => "/logschecks/scripts/setup1.php"
  http_ver # => "HTTP/1.1"
  ```
- Or [use a bit more complex pattern](http://rubular.com/r/jn8081N2DL), using [some of the modern extensions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing) and reduce the code:

  ```
  log_line = %[2010/08/23 15:25:35 [error]: (4: No such file or directory), clent: 80.154.42.54, server: localhost, request: "GET /logschecks/scripts/setup1.php HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"]
  /request: "(?<method>\S+) (?<url>\S+) (?<http_ver>\S+)"/i =~ log_line
  method # => "GET"
  url # => "/logschecks/scripts/setup1.php"
  http_ver # => "HTTP/1.1"
  ```